# I want to insert a table 7*6 but i find this error : Not in outer par mode

Tags: tables

I want to insert a table 7*6 but i find this error : Not in outer par mode..here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.0cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\begin{table}
\caption{\label{tab:table1}Tab.1 FLUKA data of carbon ion range (cm) for studied materials at different carbon ion energies }
%\begin{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline
Materials & 100MeV & 150MeV & 200MeV &  250MeV & 300MeV \\ 
\hline 
Water & 2.5188 & 5.1801 & 8.5403 & 12.492 & 16.927 \\ 
PE & 2.5188 & 5.1801 & 8.5538 & 12.505 & 16.968 \\ 
PMMA & 2.1694 & 4.4812 & 7.3575 & 10.747 & 14.616 \\ 
BONE & 1,457 & 3,0027 & 4,9516 & 7,2366 & 9,8172 \\
AL & 1.2016 & 2.4516 & 4.0376 & 5,879 & 7,9758 \\
LEAD & 0,4489 & 0,91935 & 1,5108 & 2,1962 & 2,9355 \\
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
 ]
\end{document}
```

---

Could everyone help me

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Is it a typo? In  rows 4 and 6, the decimal dot of the other rows is replaced with a comma.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}% twocolumn added
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{dblfloatfix} is in the LaTeX kernel now
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.0cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}


\begin{table*}
\caption{\label{tab:table1}FLUKA data of carbon ion range (cm) for studied materials at different carbon ion energies }
%\begin{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline
Materials & 100MeV & 150MeV & 200MeV &  250MeV & 300MeV \\ 
\hline 
Water & 2.5188 & 5.1801 & 8.5403 & 12.492 & 16.927 \\ 
PE & 2.5188 & 5.1801 & 8.5538 & 12.505 & 16.968 \\ 
PMMA & 2.1694 & 4.4812 & 7.3575 & 10.747 & 14.616 \\ 
BONE & 1,457 & 3,0027 & 4,9516 & 7,2366 & 9,8172 \\
AL & 1.2016 & 2.4516 & 4.0376 & 5,879 & 7,9758 \\
LEAD & 0,4489 & 0,91935 & 1,5108 & 2,1962 & 2,9355 \\
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table*}


\end{document}
```

- You are using `twocolumn` wrong. It is a class option. You can also change the number of columns with `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` inside the document.
- Then use `table*` for wide tables.
- Do not use `dblfloatfix`. It is in the LaTeX kernel now.

**Edit:** I removed `Tab.1` as something similar is printed by the `\caption` command. See egreg`s comment.

Comment: Quite likely `Tab.1` should be omitted.

Comment: OK, I just made the code work not worrying about `Tab.1`. ;)

Comment: I changed it, see edit. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `table*` to get a two-column float, not juggling between column modes.

However, for such a small table, it's easily possible to make it fit in a single column. Also, using `siunitx` and `booktabs`, you can improve its appearance.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}% twocolumn added
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.0cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table}[tp]
\centering

\caption{\label{tab:table1}FLUKA data of carbon ion range (cm) for studied 
materials at different carbon ion energies}

\sisetup{group-digits=integer}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\small
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.5]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=2.4]
  S[table-format=2.4]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Materials & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Energy level (\si{MeV})} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-6}
  & \num{100}
  & \num{150}
  & \num{200}
  & \num{250}
  & \num{300} \\ 
\midrule
Water & 2.5188 & 5.1801  & 8.5403 & 12.492 & 16.927 \\ 
PE    & 2.5188 & 5.1801  & 8.5538 & 12.505 & 16.968 \\ 
PMMA  & 2.1694 & 4.4812  & 7.3575 & 10.747 & 14.616 \\ 
BONE  & 1,457  & 3,0027  & 4,9516 & 7,2366 & 9,8172 \\
AL    & 1.2016 & 2.4516  & 4.0376 & 5,879  & 7,9758 \\
LEAD  & 0,4489 & 0,91935 & 1,5108 & 2,1962 & 2,9355 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note that the decimal separator is uniform, independently on which one you use in the data (you're alternating between period and comma). A common header for the data columns avoids repeating the unit of measure, so saving on the table width. Thus `\small` suffices to get it to fit in a single column.

[image]